# How to read commands from file?

Tags: files, scripting, read, moreutils-parallel

I have some `php` scripts which I run in sequential order like:

```
php index.php import file1 --offline &&
php index.php import file2 --deleteUnused &&
php index.php import file3
```

Now I have newly discovered the `parallel` command and I tried something like that:

```
parallel -j 3 -- "php index.php import file1 --offline" "php index.php import file2 --deleteUnused" "php index.php import file3"
```

And it works perfectly.

Is it possible that I could have a file where all the above commands are included, and to start `parallel` with an option to read the commands from the file?

Something like this:

```
parallel -XX myFileWithCommands.txt
```

Comment: What **parallel** version are you using? Run `parallel --version` and mention the version in the question. I have "GNU parallel 20130522" for example.

Comment: Now i get this:


`$ parallel --version
parallel: invalid option -- '-'
parallel [OPTIONS] command -- arguments
    for each argument, run command with argument, in parallel
parallel [OPTIONS] -- commands
    run specified commands in parallel`

Comment: Does `strings `which parallel` | fgrep -i gnu` output anything?

Comment: My failure was: I installed moreutils - after installing `sudo apt-get install parallel` everything works fine. Sorry for that.

Comment: I thought so :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `myFileWithCommands.txt`:

```
php index.php import file1 --offline
php index.php import file2 --deleteUnused
php index.php import file3
```

Then run **parallel** like this:

```
parallel -j 3 -- < myFileWithCommands.txt
```

Comment: wouldn't the double ampersand mean that every command will wait until the command before will be exited

Comment: @MadeOfSport, those are leftovers. I'll remove them.

Comment: If you use GNU Parallel the '-- sh -c' is not needed

Comment: @Cristian Ciupitu

I think im to dumb to execute this....

`parallel --gnu -j 3 --arg-sep " " -- sh -c < test.txt`

`parallel: invalid option -- '-'

parallel [OPTIONS] command -- arguments
for each argument, run command with argument, in parallel

parallel [OPTIONS] -- commands
run specified commands in parallel`

Comment: @MadeOfSport, drop `--gnu`, your version might not have or need it.

Comment: sorry now i get this:
@Cristian Ciupitu
`sh: 0: Illegal option -j
sh: 1: 10: not found
sh: 0: -c requires an argument
sh: 0: -c requires an argument
Im started
1404333303####`

Comment: @MadeOfSport, try this quick one: `printf "/bin/echo 1 a\n/bin/echo 2 b b\n/bin/echo 3 c c c\n/bin/echo 4 d d d d\n" | parallel -j 3 --`

Comment: @Cristian Ciupitu i didn't get any output. im working in a virtual machine with ubuntu 12.04. Maybe my version is a problem ?

Comment: Maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448887/gnu-parallel-not-working-at-all

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are two simple ways to accomplish this that I can imagine. You can either pipe the contents of the file into `parallel`, or you can write a shell script. If all you want to accomplish is this particular set of tasks, then a shell script might make more sense. It would be very short, sweet and to-the-point as well:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
parallel -j 3 -- "php index.php import file1 --offline" "php index.php import file2 --deleteUnused" "php index.php import file3"
```

Now, if you want something more generalizable (i.e., something so that you can make several sets of commands to be loaded as a group), then it might be easier to come up with a simple file format and then pipe the contents of the file into `parallel`.

The simplest way this could be done is if you had the text include the verbatim commands you wish to be run.

For example, if this were your text file (`test.txt`):

```
"php index.php import file1 --offline" "php index.php import file2 --deleteUnused" "php index.php import file3"
```

Then, you could run the following and it might work fine:

```
$ cat test.txt | parallel -j 3 --
```

You could also experiment with having a slightly more complex file format (e.g., each command on a new line and not surrounded by quotes). If you were to go down that road, you would need to do some minor parsing on the file before piping it to `parallel` which could be accomplished pretty easily with, say for example `awk`.

However, if you decide to create a more flexible file format like that, it might be helpful to create a helper shell script (or function) that would save you from having to type `awk '<whatever patterns you match> { do something }' | parallel -j3 --` each time.

Comment: this also works fine. i appreciate your help...